# How can I access a constructor member within a constructor function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry I'm not sure how to word the question.. I know it's some sort of scope issue.. but is what I'm trying to accomplish not possible?

```
app.factory('SystemStatusConnectionFactory', ['$timeout', '$q', 'SystemStatusFactory', 'SystemStatusOptionsFactory',
function ($timeout, $q, SystemStatusFactory, SystemStatusOptionsFactory) {

    var self = this;

    var SystemStatusConnectionFactory = function (ip, user, pw, options) {
        this.data = {
            count: 0
        };

    this.PollIP = function () {
      console.log(this.data.count);  //WORKS
      $timeout(function () {
            console.log(self.data.count);  //DOES NOT WORK
            console.log(this.data.count);  //DOES NOT WORK
        }, 1000);
    }
   };
... etc
```

Comment: You put `self = this` in the wrong scope. It should go inside the constructor.

Comment: A bit of proper indentation would help to recognise issues such as this.

Comment: @Bergi sigh that worked.  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard know exactly whats going on without seeing more of your code.

if you bind this with your functions you can ensure this refers to whatever context u want it to.

```
app.factory('SystemStatusConnectionFactory', ['$timeout', '$q', 'SystemStatusFactory', 'SystemStatusOptionsFactory',
(function ($timeout, $q, SystemStatusFactory, SystemStatusOptionsFactory) {

    var self = this; //this is now pointing to 'app'

    var SystemStatusConnectionFactory = (function (ip, user, pw, options) {

        this.data = {  // this is now pointing to app as well.
            count: 0
        };

        this.PollIP = function () {
            $timeout(function () {
                console.log(self.data.count);  // Self points to app.
                console.log(this.data.count);  // This points to the window object
            }, 1000);
        }
    }).bind(this);
}).bind(app) // Use bind to set app as the context of the function or 'this'
```

** I am making the assumption you want 'this' to refer to app **

Comment: thank you for the description. this technically works, but simply just putting the var self = this in the constructor as mentioned by Bergi worked

Comment: No, `this` never refers to any function.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I didnt explain it properly. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you already solved this from the comments (because I don't see why that shouldn't work in the first place), but have you tried using the `bind()` function on that timeout's function parameter? This would eliminate the need of using the `var self = this`

```
// ...
this.PollIP = function () {
      console.log(this.data.count);
      $timeout(function () {
            console.log(self.data.count);
            console.log(this.data.count);
        }.bind(this), 1000); // modified line
    }
// ...
```